# Title bar light but the theme is dark

Tags: themes

I installed elementary os and opted for Dark theme, but when I install an app through flathub or when I install a .deb (chrome for example) the title bar and other things are like the light theme, I want to know if there is a way to change this bar to dark, as it is not interesting to mix dark and light.

[image]

note that chrome itself allows a change of theme, but the system bar remains light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a similar problem by using Darkbar, which [can be found in the AppCenter](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.bluesabre.darkbar/). The source code can also be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/bluesabre/darkbar).